# How to set environment variables in Meteor (without declaring them in code)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've tried declaring them in `package.json` like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "MY_ENV=hello MY_ENV2=foo meteor"
}
```

But I got `undefined` in my code (using envs on a server side)
accessing them via `process.env`

I know about other ways of declaring that kind of sensitive data (like in `settings.json`), but I want to know how to do in another way (I'm using `macos`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line settings are available to your app, but only on the server. In client code, process.env doesn't have them. You can write a Meteor method, so that the client can ask for environment settings. There are potential security risks with this approach because you are allowing access to server settings on the client and potentially revealing them to the user.

You could put settings in a database collection, and your code will read them from there. That's probably a better way, as each deployment can easily have different settings.

If you want to use `process.env`, you can either do it on the command line,

`MY_ENV=xxx meteor --port 3010`

Or you can put them in a shell script like this

`#!/bin/bash
export MY_ENV=xxx
export MY_ENV2=yyy
meteor --port 3010`

Comment: Thank you for providing me with alternatives, but I'd still like to know about loading `env` variables from a file. After some small research, I've found out that it's possible to put all environment variables into a `.sh` file, but I still don't know how to tell `meteor` to use it

Comment: Do you want access to them on the server or the client? How are you deploying your app, because that will make a difference. If you use mup, you simply create a settings.json file, which makes it very easy

Comment: I've mentioned in my question that I'm using them on a server. For now, production in not a big concern as I'm only testing things out. Anyway, I guess, now I'm closer to the answer. If I type in my console `export X=foo`, then I can access it via `process.env.X`. I've tried to put all of my envs into `.sh` and executing it with `sh path/to/.sh` command` but got nothing

Comment: Thanks A LOT! That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

@Mikkel 's answer helped me a lot, but I still got problems with Meteor's default environment variables. So, the solution that worked for me (on `macOs`) was:

```
 #!/bin/bash
MONGO_URL="my-secret" 
SOME_API_KEY="my-another-secret" 
FOO=40 
BAR=25 
meteor --settings settings-local.json  --port 300
```

Executing this `.sh` file initialized all environment variables